# Connect one router to another one >> ip conflict

Tags: router, ip, home-networking, dhcp

I have 2 routers, the first one is connected to 2 switches 24 ports each one, and is there because it is vpn connected. The second one connects to one of these ports and is the wifi one. My problem is that when I turn on the second one, I have an IP conflict problem and the lan goes down. How can I prevent it? should I assign a static ip to the second router? I thing I cannot disable the DHCP function on both of them since the both deal with other devices. I don't know wether it is a matter of ip, subnet mask or what.

Basically my problem is simply connecting 2 routers one to another one letting both operate with other machines.

Comment: It's usual, on the same subnet, to disable DHCP on the 2nd device & let the main router handle it.

Comment: 24 port switches, VPN? Looks like company stuff, not a private installation? Then don't mess with it, ask your local admin to get it up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routers use the same class and the same IP network address.
If your fist router has the address 192.168.1.1 and your client stations have 192.168.1.2 and above, you should separately connect the second router to a notebook or station, enter its interface (which will have the same address - like 192.168.1.1) and change that to something else like 192.168.2.1.
After you do this, you can safely use both routers without conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I actually have connected the 2 routers, the first one has IP 192.168.1.1, while the second one has ip 192.168.2.1. I guess that the concerning the latter device, the 2 indicates the sublan and the 1 is the incremental ip that will be automatically dispatched to all devices on that network.

thanks!